# Prefab in Unity and HoloLens falling below the spatial mapping

Tags: unity-game-engine, hololens, 3dsmax, fbx

I'm working in a Unity application with HoloLens, where I place different prefabs across a room and I use TapToPlace to put it on a surface using SpatialMapping. I works great with some fbx models that I had, but then I received some models that I got in .max format, which I converted to FBX using 3DS Mask, they look good, but the exact setup as the other models, whenever I tap them, they are place halfway below the surface.

I've noticed that the working prefabs puts the cursor right at the bottom when in placing mode, while the "broken" ones put the cursor in the middle. Here is an example of how it looks in Unity:

Working:

[image]

Not working:

[image]

What is that circle there? it looks like the cursor, because everytime that I tap the object, the cursor is placed exactly there for each prefab, but for the ones in the center, half of the model shows below the surface, somehow it looks like it's related; is there a way to move that to the bottom as the working one looks like? if not, is there something that I need to do in 3DS max when exporting these new models to FBX? both models are using box collider, TwoHandManipulatable and TapToPlace.

Thank you, I appreciate the help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue is on the axisof the model -- the pivot point of the model is not at the bottom of the model.
If at all possible it is recommended that you fix the model in your 3D modelling application, If this is not possible, you can fix it in Unity by adding an extra parent transform, more information please see:
https://answers.unity.com/questions/62675/redefine-axis-of-an-object.html
https://answers.unity.com/questions/357698/can-we-change-the-pivot-points-of-any-gameobject.html

Comment: I ended up changing the pivot point in 3DS Max as you suggested, then exporting it back to fbx and it worked great, thanks for the help!